# 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-excel

Estoy importando aproximadamente `3000` datos de un archivo `excel` a mi tabla de mySQL desde `laravel`, lo que pasa es que me sale ese error en una llave `foranea`, especificamente en `ins_usu_id`

Adjunto el codigo de como estoy haciendo el import:

```
 public function model(array $row)
{

    $tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::firstOrCreate([
        'tipo_nombre' => $row['tipo_de_instrumento']
    ]);


    $marca = tbl_marca::firstOrCreate(
        ['mar_nombre' => $row['marca']],
        ['mar_nombre'=>$row['marca']]
    );
    $id = tbl_lab::firstOrCreate([
        'lab_cliente' => $row['cliente']
    ]);
    if ($row['fecha_proxima_calibracion'] == 'Excluido' or $row['fecha_proxima_calibracion'] == '2020/Pendiente') {
        $proximaCal=$row['fecha_proxima_calibracion'];
    }else{
        $proximaCal=\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['fecha_proxima_calibracion']);
    }

    if ($row['fecha_ultima_calibracion']=='Nuevo') {
        $ultimaCal=$row['fecha_ultima_calibracion'];
    }else{
        $ultimaCal=\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['fecha_ultima_calibracion']);
    }

    return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row['codigo_ellipse'],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row['observaciones_iniciales'],
        'ins_proximaCalibracion'=>$proximaCal,
        'ins_fechaUltimaCalibracion'=>$ultimaCal,
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row['clase_de_exactitud'],
        'ins_nSerie' => $row['numero_de_serie'],
        'ins_divOescala'=>$row['division_de_escala'],
        'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row['consecutivo_interno'],
        'ins_observaciones' =>$row['observaciones'],
        'ins_observacionFinal' => $row['observaciones_finales'],
        'ins_magnitud' => $row['magnitud'],
        'ins_modelo' => $row['modelo'],
        'ins_codActividad' => $row['codigo_de_actividad'],
        'ins_usu_id' =>  $id->lab_id,
        'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->tipo_id,
        'ins_mar_id' => $marca->mar_id,
    ]);
}
```

Probe fijandome en los `log` y me sale lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes antes de retornar la fila, válida que te trae `$tipo->tipo_id` ya sea con debugger o `Log::debug($tipo->tipo_id)` para que sepas que valor tenía esa variable antes de que falle.

Prácticamente laravel te dice que esa llave foránea no existe. Puede que en alguna iteración venga nulo ese valor.

Comment: Disculpa no he entendido como funciona ese `log` me podrias guiar mejor?, dices que lo ponga arriba de `'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->tipo_id,` Ese log va con `;`o va solo?

Comment: Otra cosa amigo porque `$tipo->tipo_id` si el error me lo arroja en `ins_usu_id`

Comment: Porque ese valor se guarda en esa llave y te indica que el valor que colocaste allí no es el correcto

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)` Me sale el siguiente error eso suponiendo que no va con `;` el codigo del `log` y si le agrego el `;` sale el siguiente error `Class 'Iluminate\Support\Facades\Log' not found`

Comment: A disculpame es Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log

Comment: Si faltaba el ; al final de la línea

Comment: Vale que se supone que debe salir en `laravel.log` no entiendo la mayor parte de lo que sale haha

Comment: Mmm prueba borrar todo el contenido de laravel.log. y luego ejecuta para que solo vea los errores de la última ejecución. Desde el principio deberías ver varios debug con los valores o solo uno si no pasó de la primera iteración.

Comment: Lo borre y se agregaron 563 lineas solo con volver a ejecutarlo, al inicio salen 416 lineas de `local.DEBUG: 150` (los numeros varian, supongo que son los ID) Luego sale el error que me muestra en pantalla Y ahí para abajo me salen rutas así `#10 D:\\prueba\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Concerns\\ManagesTransactions.php(29): `

Comment: Antes de que salga la excepción hay un debug con número coherente con tu base de datos. Puede que el último valor es el que te puede estar generando error

Comment: `local.DEBUG:130` es el ultimo dato pero ese mismo dato antes al parecer lo uso y no genero problema mm

Answer (score 0):

Importa la clase

```
use Iluminate\Support\Facades\Log;
```

Y la línea que te mencioné la colocas antes del return.

Después si quieres ver qué se imprimió en consola, te vas a la carpeta storage/logs/laravel.log o si lo tienes por fecha, el log que se haya creado para hoy. Buscas al final del archivo que fue las últimas escrituras

Comment: Dada la longitud de tus aportes quedan perfecto en una respuesta, por favor evita publicar múltiples

Comment: Gracias lo tendré en cuenta